# magento 242 admin error The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily Please wait and try again late

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image]

magento 242 admin error The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME
```

OR

Please try to reset username and password .

```
sudo php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="pearlbells" --admin-password="pear122l**all" --admin-email="pearl@gmail.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Comment: thanks for ans this is  a not work

Comment: clear cache & cookies from browser then try

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/solved-magento-2-4-2-admin-login-not-working-on-localhost/ this a solution work for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your admin login credentials are incorrect. Try to create a new admin user with below command and then try:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create
```

> For detailed info about this command run below command:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --help
```

Comment: i am already create a new user but is a not working